# How to count matches between two lists in another list

Tags: python, list, match

I am new to Python and am attempting to write a program that tells me which of the lists in a list of lists contains the most word matches to another list.  I'd like the output to be a dictionary that contains keys that are numbers which correspond to the number of the list (from the list of lists) and values which are the number of matches between the key list and the comparison list.

I've tried using several different methods of counting and have only been able to successfully get one to display the number of matches.  That method is:

```
words = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black']

list1 = ['the', 'black', 'dog']

list2 = ['the', 'blue', 'blue', 'dog']

results1 = 0

results2 = 0

for w in words:

        results1 += list1.count(w)

        results2 += list2.count(w)
```

results1

1

results2

2

How can I turn this into a dictionary with the structure (list1:1, list2:2, etc...)

My inputs are going to be a list of 26 lists, rotationssplitlist, and a reference list of words, word_list.

Optimally, I'd like to write this as a dictionarycomp.  So, something like:

```
matchdict = {[i for i in range(len(rotationssplitlist)-1)]: [word_list.count(rotationssplitlist[i] for i in range(len(rotationssplitlist)-1)]}
```

Comment: can you post what you expect your output to look like?

Comment: I'd like the output to be in the form of a list or a dictionary that maintains the original order of the template list of lists and contains the number of matches with the reference list.  So, if the first list in the template list of lists contains two matches with the reference list and the second list int he template list of lists has 0 matches, the output would be [2, 0...... etc, through x number of items in the test list.  If the output is to be a dictionary, it would be {'0: 2', '1:0'........}.  Thank you for your help it's really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to reformat your lists into a dictionary, here's a function that would create the lists into dictionary:

```
word_match = lambda match_list, list1, list2: {'list'+str(l+1): len(list([x for x in [list1, list2][l] if x in match_list])) for l in range(0, len([list1, list2]))}

words = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black']
list1 = ['the', 'black', 'dog']
list2 = ['the', 'blue', 'blue', 'dog']

print(word_match(words, list1, list2))
```

output:

```
{'list1': 1, 'list2': 2}
```

Comment: This answer worked best for me.  It provided a count of the number of matches and maintained fidelity in the order of the comparison lists.  Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `collections.counter` to get the count of words in each list then `operator.itemgetter` To get only the words that apply to the word list. Then the max of that result will be your number.

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

word_list = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black']
rotationssplitlist = [
    ['the', 'black', 'dog'],
    ['the', 'blue', 'blue', 'dog']
]
get_words = itemgetter(*word_list)
matchdict = {f'list{i}': max(get_words(Counter(l))) 
             for i, l in enumerate(rotationssplitlist, 1)}
```

This results in a dict as follows:

```
{'list1': 1, 'list2': 2}
```

Although why make a dict? The dict names are meaningless I think, you could just make a list of the match counts. They’d have the same indexes as the original list.

```
matches = [max(get_words(Counter(l))) for l in rotationssplitlist]
```

This results in:

```
[1, 2]
```

And to find the indexes of the lists that have the most matches then you could use something like:

```
[i for i, m in enumerate(matches) if m == max(matches)]
```

Results:

```
[1]
```

Comment: Thanks!  A list will work well, as long as the order is maintained.  I've never used itemgetter.

Comment: Thanks ! If you’d like, just refer to the docs for [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) If this answers your question please accept it with the check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: I realized this method does not count the number of matches.  For instance, if a one word in a list at index 0 matched the reference list, 0:1, but if two words match at index 4, it would be 4:2.

Comment: I’m not following you want them to match based on index as well somehow?

Comment: I've never used the f' strings either.  It's so useful!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dictionary with the name of the list as a key you might need to slightly change the format of your input. Otherwise, you have to take a bit of a hacky approach to get the name of a variable.

```py
words = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black']
lists = {
    'list1': ['the', 'black', 'dog'],
    'list2': ['the', 'blue', 'blue', 'dog']
}

result = {list_name: sum([list_items.count(word) for word in words]) for list_name, list_items in lists.items()}

# Result
{
    "list1": 1,
    "list2": 2
}
```

If you are only interested in getting the list with the most matches you can take a different approach.

```py
words = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black']
lists = [
    ['the', 'black', 'dog'], 
    ['the', 'blue', 'blue', 'dog']
]

result = sorted(lists, key=lambda list_items: sum([list_items.count(word) for word in words]), reverse=True)[-1]

# Result
['the', 'blue', 'blue', 'dog']
```

Comment: Strange, when I ran:

words = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black']
lists = [
    ['the', 'black', 'dog'], 
    ['the', 'blue', 'blue', 'dog']
]

result = sorted(lists, key=lambda list_items: sum([list_items.count(word) for word in words]), reverse=True)[-1]


# Result
['the', 'blue', 'blue', 'dog']


The result I got was:
['the', 'black', 'dog']